# Divide individual Pandas dataframe values by corresponding value in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a CVRP and have gotten to the point where I have a list of vehicle fleets, where each fleet is made up of a homogeneous vehicle type, and the amount of goods that should be in each fleet. The corresponding dataframe looks like this:

```
Vehicle               Quantity of Goods
v1                     8.0
v2                    12.0
v3                    16.0
v4                    12.0
```

Since each fleet is made up of a single vehicle type, I want to find the number of vehicles needed to service that quantity. I.E. I want to divide the quantity of goods the fleet has by the corresponding amount that each individual vehicle can hold, rounding up, so that I know exactly how many vehicles are active. The capacity values are found in the same .json file that I have been using to supply data to the other parts of the model, under the index data["transportation_data"]["vehicle_capacity"], where the associated dictionary is the following:

```
"vehicle_capacity": {
      "v1": 8,
      "v2": 6,
      "v3": 4,
      "v4": 3
    }
```

For example, I want to divide v1's quantity by 8, which would leave me with 1 vehicle used, or v2's quantity by 6 leaving 2 vehicles used. One thing that I have tried so far is

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.Quantity_Employed / data["transportation_data"]["vehicle_capacity"][x], axis =1)
```

However when I try this, I receive an error saying unhashable type: "Series." I have also tried

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.Quantity_Employed / data["transportation_data"]["vehicle_capacity"][x.Vehicles], axis =1)
```

But I continue to receive an error, this one being 'Series' object has no attribute 'Vehicle.' I have read through the documentation a bit, and have not found anything along these lines there either. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you show an example of what all of `data` looks like? If you have the `df` DataFrame and also convert `data` to a DataFrame, and index both of them according to Vehicle (v1, v2, etc.), then you would simply need to do something like `df['new_col'] = df['Quantity of Goods'] / data['vehicle_capacity']`, and the indexing would handle aligning this according to Vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the way you access your data, especially with "x.Quantity_Employed". This works, so the problem is probably in the lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd

capacity = {'v1' : 8, 'v2' : 12, 'v3' : 16, 'v4' : 12}
df = pd.DataFrame({'vehicle' : ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'], 'quantity' : [8, 6, 4, 3]})

f = lambda x: capacity[x['vehicle']] / x['quantity'] 

df.loc[:, 'result'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked like a charm! If anyone else is having key index errors like I was, I found that doing a df.reset_index() helped in conjunction with this.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data.  Maybe...

```
# frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vehicle': {0: 'v1', 1: 'v2', 2: 'v3', 3: 'v4'},
 'Quantity of Goods': {0: 8.0, 1: 12.0, 2: 16.0, 3: 12.0}})

  Vehicle  Quantity of Goods
0      v1                8.0
1      v2               12.0
2      v3               16.0
3      v4               12.0
```

Then...

```
# dictionary of capacity
vehicle_capacity = {
      "v1": 8,
      "v2": 6,
      "v3": 4,
      "v4": 3
    }

df['needed'] = df['Quantity of Goods'].div(df['Vehicle'].map(vehicle_capacity))

print(df)

  Vehicle  Quantity of Goods  needed
0      v1                8.0     1.0
1      v2               12.0     2.0
2      v3               16.0     4.0
3      v4               12.0     4.0
```

**Additional:**

To round up try:

```
import numpy as np

df['needed'] = df['Quantity of Goods'].div(df['Vehicle'].map(vehicle_capacity)).apply(np.ceil)

print(df)

  Vehicle  Quantity of Goods  needed
0      v1                8.1     2.0
1      v2               12.0     2.0
2      v3               16.0     4.0
3      v4               12.0     4.0
```